# Split string form one column and create a new column in python

Tags: python

I have a data -

```
data = [['0092', 'ab cd [1]'], ['887', 'ab ef [2]'], ['776', 'ab gh ab [3]'], 
        ['33101', 'ab ij [4]'], ['0922', 'ab kl [5]']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ('col_1', 'col_2'))
df

   col_1    col_2
    0092    ab cd [1]
    887     ab ef [2]
    776     ab gh ab [3]
    33101   ab ij [4]
    0922    ab kl [5]
```

I want to split col_2 and create a new column where "ab cd" is a name and 1 is its code.

```
       col_1     col_2    col_3
        0092    ab cd       1
        887     ab ef       2
        776     ab gh ab    3
        33101   ab ij       4
        0922    ab kl       5
```

I have tried this - `df['col_2'].str.split(" ", expand = True)` but it doesn't serve my purpose as it doesn't split the names accurately in terms of space occurrence. So what i was thinking to split names from starting alphabet till " [" and then create a new column based on the split. If you have any better suggestions(fewer lines of code) then please help me to code it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["col_3"] = df["col_2"].str.extract(r'^.*\[(\d+)\]')
df["col_2"] = df["col_2"].str.extract(r'^(.*?)(?=\s*(?:\[\d+\]|$))')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, btw!! it gives Nan in col_3, could you please check and revert :)

Comment: What is your actual data?  This should not be happening with the data you posted above.

Comment: Sir the actual data is same as I have posted above, I have just changed the names and numbers that's it

Comment: @KReEd My mistake.  Switch the order of operations, I had it backwards.

Comment: sir could you pls update the code, I didn't understand backward in terms of what?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you may need to reload your page.

Comment: sir in my actual data it dosnt work, col_3 shows Nan, but the data which I have posted it works :( what should I do now?

Comment: sir may i give you the data only required column in we transfer?

Comment: You should _always_ paste sample data which is representative of the actual problem.  We can only answer to data which we can see.

Comment: sir if i give u the excel file in we transfer, will it work? so that you can see where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['col_2'] = df['col_2'].str.replace(r"[[0-9]+]$","")
df['col_3'] = df['col_2'].str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Comment: This will leave whitespace at the end of `col_3`.  Also, the order of your operations should be reversed, as the first call to `str.replace` will strip away the digits which the second call to `str.extract` is trying to capture.

Comment: hey Sophocles, how are you, luckily I got you reply, do recognize me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
df['col_3'] = df['col_2'].str.extract('(\d+)')
df['col_2'] = df['col_2'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split(' ')[:-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

First use the for loop to extract the element form column col_2. Then split each values with '[' and ']' and append it to the empty list as given in following code,

```
col_2 = []
col_3 = []
for i in df['col_2']:
   col_2.append(i.split(sep=' [')[0])
   col_3.append(int(i.split(sep=' [')[1].split(sep=']')[0]))
```

Now just create two columns and add values in it like this,

```
df['col_2'] = col_2
df['col_3'] = col_3
```

Output will be like this,

```
    col_1   col_2     col_3
0   0092    ab cd     1
1   887     ab ef     2
2   776     ab gh ab  3
3   33101   ab ij     4
4   0922    ab kl     5
```